# Tagging is not accepted

Tags: discussion

In last few days, I edited some questions and did re-tagging. But they were rejected though they are  right.
Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Comment: Without a link it is really hard for us to comment...

Comment: Please don't make suggested edits like [these](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/6475). Linking is good, but it's a really minor change--whoever has the capability of answering the question will probably know what M-theory is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because your edits are too minor. Whenever you make a suggested edit, two people have to go through it. It becomes quite a waste of time when this scales up, so minor suggested edits are discouraged. If you are going to edit the post, try to fix as much as possible. If you think there's only a small fix or two, then don't suggest the edit. Note that if you LaTeXify a post that needs it, it is *generally* considered as a major edit, even if that's all you do. Though again, try and look for other parts which may be improved.

Anyway, at 500 rep you'll be able to retag posts without going through the suggested edit system, so this will be less of a problem to you...

Comment: A lot depends on who reviews your post. I almost never use the "minor edit" option; IMO there's nothing wrong with an edit as long as it does improve the post, so adding a tag that was appropriate on the question is an auto-accept in my book. But others feel differently.

Comment: It can be important for a question to have the right tags, such that people who are possibly interested in the topic the question is asking about, see it. So certain improvements of the tags can be a good thing even if no other edit is done simultaneously I think.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Yeah, opinions vary (And they're allowed to--MSO has made it pretty clear that there aren't any fixed rules to reviewing as long as you stay within some limits). I personally allow tags, but extremely minor spelling corrections are too much.

Comment: @Dilaton: True, but when making a suggested edit, one should fix as much as possible--that is rarely done. There is _almost always_ something that can be fixed.

Comment: @Manishearth  I basically agree, but if an otherwise very well formulated question gets low views and no answers, since the right people do not notice it because of mistagging, just improving the tags (without doing anything else) is good too and should NOT be be rejected by short sighted reviewers.